# Received message "Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference"

Tags: fortran

I'm currenlty learning modern Fortran, I use the TDM-GCC compiler on Windows 10 64bit.
After compiling correcly my code, I received this message when trying to run the output .exe

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  ffffffffffffffff
#1  ffffffffffffffff
#2  ffffffffffffffff
#3  ffffffffffffffff
#4  ffffffffffffffff
#5  ffffffffffffffff
#6  ffffffffffffffff
#7  ffffffffffffffff
#8  ffffffffffffffff
#9  ffffffffffffffff
#10  ffffffffffffffff
#11  ffffffffffffffff
#12  ffffffffffffffff
#13  ffffffffffffffff
#14  ffffffffffffffff
#15  ffffffffffffffff
#16  ffffffffffffffff
#17  ffffffffffffffff
#18  ffffffffffffffff
```

I understood the problem may be caused by reading I/O files. Here's the code (it's not mine, it's from the course teacher, he told me it's a runtime error, but has no idea why I get the error while reading a file):

```
program golden_ratio
! experiments with the golden ratio iterative relation
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: rk = kind(1.0d0)
  real(rk) :: phi, phi_old
  real(rk) :: phi_start, tol
  integer :: i, max_iter

    open(11,FILE='goldenfile.in',STATUS='old')
    read(11,*) phi_start, tol, max_iter
    close(11)
    ! how I wrote the input file
    ! 5.0
    ! 0.0001
    ! 1000

  phi_old = phi_start
  do i=1,max_iter
    phi = 1.0d0/phi_old + 1.0d0
    if (abs(phi - phi_old) < tol) exit
    phi_old = phi
  end do

  open(12,FILE='goldenfile.out',STATUS='replace')
  write(12,100) 'Start value:',phi_start
  write(12,100) 'Tolerance:',tol
  write(12,'(2(A," ",I11,"  "))') 'Ended at iteration:', i, 'of', max_iter
  write(12,100) 'Final value:',phi
  close(12)
    print *, 'Output file created'

100 format(A," ",F13.10)
end program golden_ratio
```

So this problem occurs when I try to open the input file 'goldenfile.in' (which is present in the same directory, defined as I wrote in the commented section, obviously it doesn't contain the comment marks).
It also occurs when I forgo using the input file, and I try to overwrite the output file 'goldenfile.out' after having obtained it a first time. Using 'replace' or not doesn't change the situation.
The strange thing is that the compilation goes right.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention

Comment: Learn to compile your code for debugging `-g -fbacktrace ` enable warnings `-Wall ` and runtime checks `-fcheck=all `.

Comment: One could start by writing the output to the screen... That will get you down the track to which line may be the issue, or not...

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in your code, and I tried it on my Linux machine with gfortran v 5.4.0 and it worked fine. Take @VladimirF comment and add some debugging parameters to the compile step. And maybe post the compile command here as well.

Comment: In addition, if you already suspect I/O issues, it would be a good idea to catch both `iostat` (integer) and `iomsg` (string) and try to output these if `iostat` is not zero. This works with every `open`, `read`, `write`, and even `close` call.

Comment: It looks like a mess in the libraries or an installation problem or something. But hard to say if the OP never comes back to update... `ffffffffffffffff` is a very strange address.